# Confusion about the GWT generated files

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt

I'm a newbie to GWT. I just read the Google GWT online tutorial and some other documents, and now there are two things confusing me:

1. I know that GWT generates javascript files (.js) from Java code, but how about HTML? Does GWT also generate .HTML files based on the Java code or not?
2. Does the process of GWT's generating javascript and HTML(if any) files happen on server side? Or we just generate these files when we develop on our own machine and then deploy the generated .js and .html files into server side?

Anyone can help answer the two questions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. GWT will compile your code into JavaScript. All UI is stored in this JavaScript code. It does not generate any static HTML-files *(#1)*. The Browser will do this, after the GWT application is loaded. All UI is created with [DOM.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) (or a browser dependend fallback). In an typical GWT application, there is only one html-file (called "hostpage"). This file will include the `module/module.nocache.js`.
2. The compile for production *(#2)* use is a step, made before you serve the application. You will will need to deploy the files onto the server. If your application contains backend-logic (RPC-calls) you have some serverside code, database access, for example.

*1: 
Depending on your compiler-flags, GWT may also compile a list of HTML-files, which contains the inlined JavaScript code.

*2:
If you use the "SuperDevMode", the compile process is done witin the server, while you are loading the application.